# Android TabHost.setCurrentTab() not working

Tags: android

I have a `TabActivity` that I am having problems after the device changes orientation. Followed some places on how to keep the current tab open after the change, but even tho I do get the correct tab number, it always sets it back to 0.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    int currentTab = 1;
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        currentTab = savedInstanceState.getInt("tabNumber");

    tabHost = getTabHost(); // (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    createTabs(tabHost);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(currentTab);
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("tabNumber", getTabHost().getCurrentTab());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to yout manifest file

..

```
activity android:name="youractivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

...

Leslie

Comment: I am facing the same problem and made the above changes as well. But still when i set tabhost.setCurrentTab(2) instead of taking it to 3rd tab, it shows 1st tab.

Comment: ok, i got it solved by making setting currenttab after adding all tabs in tabhost. Previously i was setting it each time while  creating tab.